# hide and show in jQuery selected element

Tags: jquery

I need to create a slideshow that displays one image at a time and each image is shown/hidden clicking on a div. I came to a login in jQuery, but this hide just one time and the other images are shown one after another without being hidden. Plus, I cannot click on the same div once been clicked.

EDITED with code snipppet.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('.imageslide:first').attr('current', true).show();
  $('.slider-block').append('<div class="pagination-slider"></div>') //add the div for the pagination

    var titles_pagination = $('.slider-title');
    titles_pagination.each(function(){
        $('.pagination-slider').append('<div class="select-image" alt="go to image">'+$(this).text()+"</div>") //gets the titles and relative urls to the slider items
    });

    $('.imageslide').each(function( i, el ){ //add a numbered id for each figure
        $(el).attr('id','image-num-'+i);
    });

    $('.select-image').click(function(){
        var index = $('.select-image').index(this); //the index of the selector
        var imageShown = $('.imageslide[current]').index(); //the index of the current image shown
        if (index == imageShown) {
            //pass
        }
        else {
            $('.imageslide').eq(imageShown).attr('current', false).hide();
            $('.imageslide').eq(index).attr('current', true).fadeIn();
            
        }
    });
});
```

```css
.imageslide{
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  }

img{
  width: 300px;
}

.slider-block{
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;

}

.slider-title{
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  padding: 0.6em;
  padding-left: 1.4em;
  padding-right: 1.4em;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.pagination-slider{
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.select-image{
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.6em;
  padding-left: 1.4em;
  padding-right: 1.4em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
    <div class="slider-block">
    <figure class="imageslide"><a class="item-slider"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/48/Moods_of_Nature.jpg" /><span class="slider-title">Fig 1</span></a></figure>
    
    <figure class="imageslide"><a class="item-slider" ><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/Akash_in_mood.jpg" /><span class="slider-title">Fig 2</span></a></figure>
    
    <figure class="imageslide"><a class="item-slider"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/Mystic_afternoon_mood_at_Lake_K%C3%B6nigssee.jpg" /><span class="slider-title">Fig 3</span></a></figure>
    
    <figure class="imageslide"><a class="item-slider"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/58/Great_Mood.jpg" /><span class="slider-title">Fig 4</span></a></figure>
    
    <figure class="imageslide"><a class="item-slider"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/ff/The_Mood_to_be_Wooed.jpg" /><span class="slider-title">Fig 5</span></a></figure>
    </div>
```

Comment: Please provide enough html/css to create a [mre] that demonstrates the issue. If you click on `<>` in question editor you make it a runnable snippet here in the page

Comment: Done. Thank you, I didn't know how to do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basic problem is setting the attribute "current" to false does not remove the attribute so if you inspect the elements in dev tools inspector you will see there are more than one. This throws off the indexing when you use `$('.imageslide[current]').index();`

I suggest that instead of using a custom attribute you just add and remove a className "current" instead

Working example

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.imageslide:first').addClass('current').show();
  $('.slider-block').append('<div class="pagination-slider"></div>') //add the div for the pagination

  var titles_pagination = $('.slider-title');
  titles_pagination.each(function() {
    $('.pagination-slider').append('<div class="select-image" alt="go to image">' + $(this).text() + "</div>") //gets the titles and relative urls to the slider items
  });

  var $slides = $('.imageslide');
  
  $('.select-image').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).index(); //the index of the selector
    var $nextSlide = $slides.eq(index);
    // don't do anything if same indexed slide already has current class
    if (!$nextSlide.hasClass('current')) {
      $slides.filter('.current').removeClass('current').fadeOut(function() {
        $nextSlide.addClass('current').fadeIn()
      });
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.imageslide {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
}

img {
  width: 300px;
}

.slider-block {
  justify-content: center;
  display: flex;
}

.slider-title {
  position: absolute;
  top: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  padding: 0.6em;
  padding-left: 1.4em;
  padding-right: 1.4em;
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
}

.pagination-slider {
  margin-top: 1em;
}

.select-image {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  padding: 0.6em;
  padding-left: 1.4em;
  padding-right: 1.4em;
  margin: 0.5em;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="slider">
  <div class="slider-block">
    <figure class="imageslide">
      <a class="item-slider"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/4/48/Moods_of_Nature.jpg" /><span class="slider-title">Fig 1</span></a>
    </figure>

    <figure class="imageslide">
      <a class="item-slider"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d5/Akash_in_mood.jpg" /><span class="slider-title">Fig 2</span></a>
    </figure>

    <figure class="imageslide">
      <a class="item-slider"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/a/ac/Mystic_afternoon_mood_at_Lake_K%C3%B6nigssee.jpg" /><span class="slider-title">Fig 3</span></a>
    </figure>

    <figure class="imageslide">
      <a class="item-slider"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/58/Great_Mood.jpg" /><span class="slider-title">Fig 4</span></a>
    </figure>

    <figure class="imageslide">
      <a class="item-slider"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/f/ff/The_Mood_to_be_Wooed.jpg" /><span class="slider-title">Fig 5</span></a>
    </figure>
  </div>
```

Comment: Supposing I've got more then one slider, how can I iterate through them so that every slider has their elements and just theirs? I'm trying to put a each function attached to the `slider` class, but I can't come up with a solution.

Comment: Within the each you would set `$slider = $(this)` then use `$slider.find()` for the various elements so everything is isolated to the specific slider instance